# Setup bitcoin cash with bitcored

Tags: bitcoin-cash, full-node, bitcore

I saw that https://blockdozer.com has insight-api for bitcoin cash blockchain. But i cant find doc how to setup bitcoin cash with existing bitcore node. I have already synchronized full bitcored node and able to use it insight-api.

Answer (score 1):

https://blockexplorer.com also has this same functionality. I believe some bandaids need to be placed on insight-ui in order to get the cashaddr format working fine, but there is a branch of bitcore that is designed to work with bitcoin cash.

https://github.com/bitpay/bitcore-lib/tree/cash

Comment: is it enough to install bitcore and add there bitcoin cash lib?